# Why do I get WebGL Runtime error: "RuntimeError: indirect call to null" on Gamejolt, after I publish on it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, webgl

I'm trying to publish a game on Gamejolt, but I get the runtime error mentioned in the title.
Here are the screenshots of the full error message, and my Settings for Unity Build and Player:
[image: full error message]

[image]

[image]

There are no runtime errors in my game, so it's something with the WebGL configuration I guess, but I can't figure it out. I searched the web for this particular error, but couldn't find a solution. Unity 2019 haven't had these kinda troubles with WebGL, and I have published games with it. It's only after the upgrade to 2021 that I'm having issues with WebGL, and PC builds have no issues whatsoever. Any suggestions on how to fix the error please?

(Link to the game page, which contains the downloadable for Windows: [https://gamejolt.net/?token=JBHvViUyXHk8yCaRtQvQ9afAWep2Sn](https://gamejolt.com/games/3d_flight_survival/781776))

Comment: Please share error messages as text not as images. This would make it easier for others to help you.
Also please clarify how the link can be used to recreate the error message.

Comment: Tnx 4 the input. This is the entire error (does not occur inside unity or VS obviously, only when the WebGL upload and try to play):
RuntimeError: indirect call to null
blob:https://cdn-files-browser.gamejolt.net/1815547f-3bbb-46d8—
ac7f-5b394859d8af line 3 > WebAssembly.instantiate2wasm-
function[29650]:0x9b83fc
blob:https://cdn-files-browser.gamejolt.net/1815547f-3bbb-46d8-
ac7f-Sb394859d8af line 3 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-
function[27230]:0x957694
JS_ScreenOrientation_eventHandlerblob:https://cdn-files-
browser.gamejolt.net/1815547f-3bbb-46d8-
ac7f—5b394859d8af:3:38322

Comment: Have you tried running on localhost? And did the game launch successfully with Unity 2019?

Comment: Yes on both 2019 and 2021 it works with no issues. Running on localhost gives the same error, on every browser I've tested. I tried uploading a dummy game just now, and it works, with the same settings. I dunno what's wrong with this game's build..